# DateTime + 2x Time vs. DateTime + Duration for storing time

Tags: datetime, database-schema

I'm trying to implement a `ReservationController` which is responsible for taking reservations of something for a specific time range. So far I guessed using one column for the Date (`DateTime`) and two columns for the time span (2x `Time`) in the database would be a good idea. Especially when it comes to queries on date, this approach is easier because I know, that the `DateTime` column is always set to 12am. So I just query `DateTime`.Today for instance. But now I'm getting into trouble with reservations which are passing the day border (eg. Today 22pm - Tomorrow 1am). Could you please give me some advice what is a common solution for this problem (what database schema I should use)?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought just two `DateTimes` would be enough? You can still query whether start datetime or end datetime is today (i.e >= today midnight and < tomorrow midnight).

Perhaps I am missing something - were there other queries you need to do, or were you worried about optimisation of this query? It should be fine, if you add one or more indexes for the `DateTime` columns.